# what is the difference between a multiple group ratio analysis and computing correlation?

Tags: classification, correlation

I'm very new to all this so please bare with me. All advises and corrections are welcome.

**Context**

I have the following dataset:

```
id,level,condition
#123,1,0
#576,1,0
#663,2,1
#945,1,1
#712,3,0
#981,1,1
#851,3,1
#361,1,1
etc...
```

the id for each user is unique. I have one row per user. The level is the level of engagement for each user. Level 3 represent most engaged user. The condition is an interaction the user did during it’s user journey.

*The hypothesis I’d like to validate is that more engaged users are more willing to meet condition (i.e condition = 1).*

I have two approaches I can use to validate my hypothesis. I'd like to understand the pros and cons between these two approaches.

**Approach #1**

From what I understand I can use the Pearson correlation coefficient to demonstrate the correlation between user engagement level and condition. I’m working with BigQuery so I would basically run the following query on my dataset:

```
SELECT
  CORR(level, condition)
FROM 
  my_data_set
```

Let's assume that the dataset is normally distributed for this question.

**Approach #2**

my second approach would be to sum the condition and divide it by the number of users inside each group. The query would looks like this:

```
SELECT
  level,
  SUM(condition)/COUNT(*) as ratio
FROM
  `my_dataset`
GROUP BY
  1
```

from the limited knowledge I have in statistical field the level with the better ratio would be an higher correlation between condition and level of user engagement.

**Question**

Does the second approche make sense? What are the differences between these two approaches.